# How does copy-on-write work in fork-exec?

Tags: c, linux, fork, exec, copy-on-write

A process `fork`s a child process, and calls `exec()` in the child process.
With copy-on-write, after `fork` the parent process and child process share the memory.

When the child process calls `exec()` to load another process, will Linux copy the parent memory to the new memory and the child loads another process also to this new memory? If so, does that mean the process forked with copy-on-write got no data when doing fork-exec?

Comment: child gets a new address space. not parent

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more appropriate for the [Unix & Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Also, I think Google already has the answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

> With copy-on-write, after `fork` the parent process and child process share the memory.

Yes for reading and no for writing. A new address space is created for the forked child process, only it is not populated until a write to it occurs by the child.

If `fork()` is immediately followed by `exec()`, the address space created for the child while `fork()`ing typically isn't used but is replaced by a new one, namely the one created for the process `exec ()`ed.

Comment: The key misunderstanding in the question, it seems to me, is that the `exec` completely replaces the original memory mappings with a brand new set, wholly unrelated to those in the pre-exec process.  Some attributes carry over to the exec'd process (most file descriptors, for example), but many do not (shared memory segments, memory mapped segments, etc).